# How to know how much time a computer monitor has been on?

Tags: monitors, displays

I'm thinking about buying a second monitor of the same model as my current main display (Asus MX279) and because it is now kind of old (I've bought mine in 2015) I have to buy it used.

I've found someone near me selling one of these as "new" but I have no trust in this kind of claim so I would like to know if there is any way to check how much time the screen has been running?

Because I already have the same model I can install everything required on my laptop beforehand.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If a monitor has any hope of reporting that kind of data, it would probably be exposed over [DDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel). There are utilities on Linux that can get or set values on a monitor using this protocol.

Answer (score 3):

After some more research, I have found a solution : **the factory menu** (or service menu)!

To open this menu on my monitor, the procedure is the following:

- Turn on the monitor while keeping the "Menu" button pressed
- As soon as something appears, release the button and press it again
- the normal menu appear, but a little "F" is now visible on the bottom left, select it and press "Menu"

Then the service menu appears, mine looks like this:

[image]

What do you think about 13k hours of operation? How many hours do you think it has left?